# How to test untrimmed values in cucumber's tables

Tags: testing, cucumber, whitespace

How to test untrimmed values like "    hola"  (without double quotes) in examples of scenarios outline?

```
Examples:
  |Fullname|Email|Password|
  |       Felipe|felipe@gmail.com|1234567|
  |Felipe       |felipe@gmail.com|1234567|
  |   Felipe    |felipe@gmail.com|1234567|
```

Comment: I am testing the auto_strip_attributes gem. See https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is overkill. You shouldn't need deep testing of code that isn't yours. A single example should be sufficient to prove the integration, e.g.:

```
Given I am adding a new person
When I fill in a name containing whitespace
Then the name should be saved with the whitespace stripped
```

Comment: in others words, How can I use whitespaces in examples of  Scenario Outline?. Is there any delimiter character? Suppose that I need them to test my code